# multidimensional array filled with multiple sql answers

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

i want to fill and send a multidimensional array from php to js.

first i execute the sql query

```
$query = "SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 10";
$value = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

the next step is filling the array

```
    $data = array();
    $counter = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $value )){
       $data[$counter] = array($row['value1'], $row['value2'], $row['value3']);
       $counter++;
    }
```

but when i try to test the output with

```
echo "" . json_encode( $data , JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

there is nothing displayed on the website

this correct output i get after while loop with print_r
{ "1": { "value1": "52", "value2": "12", "value3": "821" }, "2": { "value1": "52", "value2": "12"} }

Comment: Your counter should start at 0, not 1. Can you try `print_r` instead of `json_encode` for test purposes? Also, are you sure your query is returning rows?

Comment: yeah i tested it the query returns rows. When i print the array it return the right and filled array

Comment: Can you post the data structure? We can't run your query, and it sounds like that's not the problem since your `print_r` is working as expected, so a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example would be a dump of `$data` and the call to `json_encode` producing incorrect or no output.

Answer (score 0):

why not using `mysqli_fetch_array` :

```
   $query = mysqli_query("SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 10";);
   $data = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   $data[] = $row;
   }
   echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: this works with an simple array. but as soon as  i add another row (the value2) i get no result

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated, use mysqli_query.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array is deprecated too, use mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: @TimFenil you don't need fill array value by value not different in multidimensional

Comment: yeah you are right it worked your way and the array is filled correctly but i still cant get it through json_encode

Comment: @TimFenil try it now :)

Comment: i copy pasted your code and still with the print_r it shows me the correct array filled with my data from the database but the output with json_encode returns nothing.
with print_r before the json_encode i see the array like this : 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [value1] => 43675 [value2] => 23020  .... etc.

Comment: @TimFenil before echo can you print this : $json = json_encode($data);

Comment: yeah but i still dont get an output

Comment: maye you please use json_last_error to check if there were errors in json_encode. php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php